# html drop down menus not working in firefox and everything is wrong in older versions of IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Good evening everybody I am having trouble with my drop down menu's in firefox and IE.

I mistakenly developed this page and tested everything on chrome but when a buddy was checking it for me he used firefox and said he was not able to use my navigation. Could somebody please point me in the right direction Thanks.

And if anybody could point me in the right direction on getting my page to look good on IE that would be great

here is the code

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"html">Register/login</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Email Password</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Answer Security Questions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

here is the css

```
nav {
    height:80px;
    width:1024px;
    }
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    }
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    }
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    }
nav ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 75px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    z-index:100;
    }
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }
li {
    float: left;
    }
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    }
nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }
nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
    }
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
    }   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;}
}
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    }
li > ul {
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    }
li:hover ul, li.over ul{ display: block; }

#article{
    height:500px;
    width:1024px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    }
#article>h1 {
    text-align:center;
    }
#legaljibjab {
    height:30px;
    width:1024px;
    border:black solid thin;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what is not working as you expect. Thanks.

Comment: For older versions of IE, you have a lot of unsupported styles that will cause some chaos in old IE. Gradients, pseudo, and you are using HTML5 elements like `nav`. Older IE's don't know what a `nav` tag is so they will inherit none of those styles.

Comment: It seems to work okay for me in Firefox if you remove the surplus quote mark in the href attribute of the first list item. http://jsfiddle.net/S7ZZJ/

Comment: When i hover over the elements in firefox the menus are not dropping down, they work fine in chrome but not on firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older browsers do not support the new styles of HTML5 certain things may be out of order because of the older support for the html try IE 10 or Chrome then see what happens.

Your html and css looks right but to be sure download a newer browser. Also try taking out the `<nav>` element.

Comment: The page works great in chrome but the dropdowns are actually appearing at the bottom of the screen in firefox and IE is just a mess

Comment: I dont actually use firefox I had a complaint from a friend and checked it out im my college computer lab heres a link to the page.. hover over the navigation items and youll see they show up on the bottom of the screen but if you open it in chrome it will appear where you would expect it. Unless ive messed up my code because my school does not have chrome. 
http://vps8383.inmotionhosting.com/~jsnow/

Comment: Works fine on my version of firefox

Comment: The navigation is on top and the sub menus appear when hovered over.

Comment: what is the most current version of firefox my school is using 7.0.1

Comment: I am running 24.0 The current version.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the invalid html of this line?

```
<a href="#"html">Register/login</a>
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know what that `"#"html"` is for.

Comment: nope still didn't get it.... i have no idea how that got in there though.... good spot though probably running on 3 am and mt dew at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I see that your second `<li>` tag has a random `html` tag in there which probably isn't helping. Running your code through an html validator will work wonders for you. A quick Google search will provide you with many different options.

The `<nav>` tag is an html5 tag and is not supported by IE8 and older. I'm guessing your friend was probably using an older version of IE. When developing for cross browser compatability you need to keep in mind that some tags & techniques differ in compatability. There are many sites out there that you can use to check this. In school, I often used - [Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)

As for Firefox not working, I can't really say. Firefox is compatible with the `<nav>` tag so that should be working. Are you getting any errors in your browser's error console?

Comment: Are you not allowed to have humor in your posts? I don't remember seeing that in rules anywhere. The line you edited out was a reference to a tv show. His name is John snow. You know nothing John snow. Why so serious?